# Android Studio TextView disappears after activity change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, textview

I've looked into countless posts but can't seem to figure this one out.
After I change the font/color/size of my textview (which is in the main activity) through the ChangeFont activity, the textview in the main activity seems to just disappear.

Here is the MainActivity.java

```
package assignment02.csc214.assignment04;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.text.style.UnderlineSpan;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// keys to pass data in to ChangeFontActivity
static final String KEY_BOLD = "assignment02.csc214.assignment04.BOLD";
static final String KEY_ITALIC = "assignment02.csc214.assignment04.ITALIC";
static final String KEY_UNDERLINE =    "assignment02.csc214.assignment04.UNDERLINED";

static final String KEY_BLUE = "assignment02.csc214.assignment04.BLUE";
static final String KEY_RED = "assignment02.csc214.assignment04.RED";
static final String KEY_YELLOW = "assignment02.csc214.assignment04.YELLOW";

static final String KEY_20SP = "assignment02.csc214.assignment04.20SP";
static final String KEY_30SP = "assignment02.csc214.assignment04.30SP";
static final String KEY_40SP = "assignment02.csc214.assignment04.40SP";

static final String KEY_MESSAGE = "Enter message here.";

private TextView mMainTV;

private boolean mUnderlined = false;

private int mBlue = 0xff0000ff;
private int mRed = 0xffff0000;
private int mYellow = 0xffffff00;

private int m20 = 20;
private int m30 = 30;
private int m40 = 40;

private static final int REQUEST_FONT = 2;
private static final int REQUEST_MESSAGE = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mMainTV = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_main_activity);

    Button fontButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.fontButton);

    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        String message = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_MESSAGE);
        mMainTV.setText(message);
    }
    fontButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChangeFontActivity.class);

            // passing data in
            // font data
            Typeface typeface = mMainTV.getTypeface();
            intent.putExtra(KEY_BOLD, typeface.isBold());
            intent.putExtra(KEY_ITALIC, typeface.isItalic());
            intent.putExtra(KEY_UNDERLINE, mUnderlined);

            // color data
            intent.putExtra(KEY_BLUE, mBlue);
            intent.putExtra(KEY_RED, mRed);
            intent.putExtra(KEY_YELLOW, mYellow);

            // size data
            intent.putExtra(KEY_20SP, m20);
            intent.putExtra(KEY_30SP, m30);
            intent.putExtra(KEY_40SP, m40);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_FONT);
        }
    });
    Button messageButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.changeMessageButton);
    messageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChangeMessageActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(KEY_MESSAGE, mMainTV.getText().toString());
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_MESSAGE);
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // use bundle to save information
    outState.putString(KEY_MESSAGE, mMainTV.getText().toString());
}
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    String message = savedInstanceState.getString(KEY_MESSAGE);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if( resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED ) {
        boolean bold = data.getBooleanExtra(KEY_BOLD, false);
        boolean italic = data.getBooleanExtra(KEY_ITALIC, false);
        boolean underlined = data.getBooleanExtra(KEY_UNDERLINE, false);
        updateFont(bold, italic, underlined);

        boolean blue = data.getBooleanExtra(KEY_BLUE, false);
        boolean red = data.getBooleanExtra(KEY_RED, false);
        boolean yellow = data.getBooleanExtra(KEY_YELLOW, false);
        updateColor(blue, red, yellow);

        boolean text20 = data.getBooleanExtra(KEY_20SP, false);
        boolean text30 = data.getBooleanExtra(KEY_30SP, false);
        boolean text40 = data.getBooleanExtra(KEY_40SP, false);
        updateSize(text20, text30, text40);
    }
    if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED){
        CharSequence message = data.getCharSequenceExtra(KEY_MESSAGE);
        mMainTV.setText(message);
    }
}
protected void updateSize(boolean text20, boolean text30, boolean text40){
    if (text20)
        mMainTV.setTextSize(m20);
    else if (text30)
        mMainTV.setTextSize(m30);
    else if (text40)
        mMainTV.setTextSize(m40);

}
protected void updateColor(boolean blue, boolean red, boolean yellow){
    if (blue)
        mMainTV.setTextColor(mBlue);
    else if (red)
        mMainTV.setTextColor(mRed);
    else if (yellow)
        mMainTV.setTextColor(mYellow);
}
protected void updateFont(boolean bold, boolean italic, boolean underline){
    Typeface typeface = mMainTV.getTypeface();
    int style = Typeface.NORMAL;
    if(bold && italic) {
        style = Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC;
    }
    else if(bold) {
        style = Typeface.BOLD;
    }
    else if(italic) {
        style = Typeface.ITALIC;
    }
    Typeface newTypeface = Typeface.create(typeface, style);
    mMainTV.setTypeface(newTypeface);

    if(underline) {
        CharSequence message = mMainTV.getText();
        SpannableString content = new SpannableString(message);
        content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, content.length(), 0);
        mMainTV.setText(content);
        mUnderlined = true;
    }
    else {
        // reset whole message
        mMainTV.setText(mMainTV.getText().toString());
        mUnderlined = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Here is ChangeFontActivity.java

```
  package assignment02.csc214.assignment04;

  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.CheckBox;

public class ChangeFontActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
      private CheckBox mBoldBox;
      private CheckBox mItalicBox;
      private CheckBox mUnderlineBox;

      private CheckBox mBlue;
      private CheckBox mRed;
      private CheckBox mYellow;

      private CheckBox m20;
      private CheckBox m30;
      private CheckBox m40;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_font);

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    // get the appropriate checkboxes and set data from MainActivity
    mBoldBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_bold);
    mBoldBox.setChecked(intent.getBooleanExtra(MainActivity.KEY_BOLD, false));

    mItalicBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_italic);
    mItalicBox.setChecked(intent.getBooleanExtra(MainActivity.KEY_ITALIC, false));

    mUnderlineBox = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.check_underline);
    mUnderlineBox.setChecked(intent.getBooleanExtra(MainActivity.KEY_UNDERLINE, false));

    mBlue = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.color_blue);
    mBlue.setChecked(intent.getBooleanExtra(MainActivity.KEY_BLUE, false));

    mRed = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.color_red);
    mRed.setChecked(intent.getBooleanExtra(MainActivity.KEY_RED, false));

    mYellow = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.color_yellow);
    mYellow.setChecked(intent.getBooleanExtra(MainActivity.KEY_YELLOW, false));

    m20 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sp_20);
    m20.setChecked(intent.getBooleanExtra(MainActivity.KEY_20SP, false));

    m30 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sp_30);
    m30.setChecked(intent.getBooleanExtra(MainActivity.KEY_30SP, false));

    m40 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.sp_40);
    m40.setChecked(intent.getBooleanExtra(MainActivity.KEY_40SP, false));

    Button OKButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
    OKButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent data = new Intent();
            data.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_BOLD, mBoldBox.isChecked());
            data.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_ITALIC, mItalicBox.isChecked());
            data.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_UNDERLINE, mUnderlineBox.isChecked());

            data.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_BLUE, mBlue.isChecked());
            data.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_RED, mRed.isChecked());
            data.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_YELLOW, mYellow.isChecked());

            data.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_20SP, m20.isChecked());
            data.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_30SP, m30.isChecked());
            data.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_40SP, m40.isChecked());

            setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
            finish();
        }
    });
    Button cancelButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_cancel);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
            finish();
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the ChangeMessageActivity.java

```
package assignment02.csc214.assignment04;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class ChangeMessageActivity extends Activity implements MyFragment.MessageChangeListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_change_message);

    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.change_message_activity, fragment)
            .commit();
}
@Override
public void messageChanged(CharSequence message) {
    Intent data = new Intent();
    data.putExtra(MainActivity.KEY_MESSAGE, message);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    finish();
}

@Override
public void messageCanceled() {
    setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
    finish();
 }
}
```

And lastly the MyFragment.java (Only the changeMessage activity is run using a fragment)

```
package assignment02.csc214.assignment04;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

public interface MessageChangeListener {
    public void messageChanged(CharSequence message);
    public void messageCanceled();
}
private MessageChangeListener mMessageChangeListener;

public MyFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    mMessageChangeListener = (MessageChangeListener)context;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);

    final EditText editText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.setText(getArguments().getString(MainActivity.KEY_MESSAGE));
    Button okButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.activity3_okButton);
    okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mMessageChangeListener.messageChanged(editText.getText());
        }
    });

    Button cancelButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.activity3_cancelButton);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mMessageChangeListener.messageCanceled();
        }
    });
    return view;
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `onActivityResult()` method is trying to handle responses from two different child activities, one of which returns a message and one of which does not, without distinguishing between the two of them.

Your `MainActivity` starts one of two different child activities: one to change the font, and one to change the message.  When it starts each activity it provides a request code: either `REQUEST_MESSAGE` or `REQUEST_FONT`.

When the child activity returns a result, the request code will come back along with it.  In this way, you can tell which activity is returning a result and decide what to do with it.  You should only update the message if request code is `REQUEST_MESSAGE`, and you should only update the font if the request code is `REQUEST_FONT`.

As written your `onActivityResult()` always tries to do BOTH as long as the user didn't press the cancel button (note that BOTH of your if statements will be true regardless of which child activity is returning a result).  This means that you are trying to change the message displayed even when the `ChangeFontActivity` is the one returning a result (and the result does not include a message).  The message is `null`, and so the text "disappears" from the screen.